# What does * apply to?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm considering replacing

```
body, label, p, div, input{
  padding:  0px;
  margin:  0px;
}
```

with

```
* { 
  margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}
```

Is `*` a catch all? What elements is it applied to?

I'm transferring some CSS over from [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/3979221/cb69c5e8ccf0745fff2c94b47b27b108931f1a15) and I need this for it to display correctly but I've never used `*` before.

Comment: Yes, it's a catch all

Comment: Yes, `*` catches all elements and you probably don't want to use it

Comment: The reason @Pekka웃 says "you probably don't want to use it" is simple: Not only does the rule apply to every element individual, but will cascade all over the place. This will greatly clutter any code inspector showing you the applied rules.

Comment: I'll remove it once I figure out what was breaking my code.  It was a quick fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It applies to [every element in the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector), from the root `<html>` element to any other element that exists. Also note that this selector has *no specificity*, so any declaration for the same element and property will override it.

Answer (score 3):

`*` means "all elements" - it is not a good idea to use in general because if you have deep levels of nested elements, it will match every single element in that chain and cascade a lot more than is necessary.

Comment: It just depends on the user case [and OCD level], it's useful for doing a reset and have full control of your css in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers say it applies to all elements that are descendants of the selector you use it in conjunction with.

One use case that is useful for the `*` (that isn't about hacking CSS to work with IE) is with a direct child selector:

```
body div.content > * {
    ...
}
```

This example will select all direct children of div.content regardless of tag type, and only the direct children.